# ADO Repeated SQL Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ado

I have a query that uses a sub query with the same parameters, so it looks something like this:

```
strSelect = _
"SELECT a.State, a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.JobTitle " & _
"FROM apples a " & _
"LEFT JOIN ( " & _
    "SELECT a.RecordNumber, " & _
    "CASE WHEN j.JobTitle IS NULL THEN j.JobTitle2 ELSE j.jobtitle END " & _
    "FROM apples a " & _
    "LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.RecordNumber = a.RecordNumber " & _
    strWhere & _
    ") b ON b.RecordNumber = a.RecordNumber "

strWhere = _
"WHERE a.JobState = ? " & _
"AND a.JobDate = ? "
```

The sub-query in real life is less pointless than the one in the example.

The question here is if I repeat `strWhere`, then is there a way to get the parameters to work for the resulting `strSQL = strSelect & strWhere` statement? The issue is that I have two parameters, but they're repeated, so it would be four parameters for the `strSQL` statement, but I would prefer to not repeat my parameters when I declare them.

I have a feeling I'm missing something pretty obvious here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you just move this whole thing to a stored procedure instead? It would not only make this easier to code it would give you better separation between the application and the data.

Comment: I have read-only access to this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use named parameters:

Try using named parameters for example:

```
WHERE a.JobState = @JobDate
```

and

```
AND a.JobDate = @JobDate
```

Then, when you add your parameters you will only need to add them once. It will look something like this:

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "JobDate";
param.Value         = theDate;
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks. I was under the impression that parameters were positional even if they're named, essentially meaning the names are ignored.